# I cannot install mongodb3 on ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, mongodb

I have `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-27-generic x86_64)` installed in my server
When i want to install mongodb3 with below commands :

```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
  sudo echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.3 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.3.list
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated mongodb-org
```

I got below error with command `sudo apt-get update` :

```
 Fetched 5,601 kB in 1min 5s (84.9 kB/s)                                        
 W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
 W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.4/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

 W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.3/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

 W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.3/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And i got below error with command `sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated mongodb-org`

```
 E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with that repository, because 403 Forbidden suggests an issue on the configuration on that side.  Are yo usure you're using the correct repository?

Comment: i don't know my friend you tell me is that right? how can find that and how can i install mongodb3

Comment: Try again - this could have been a temporary issue because I can see the files it's trying to get without issue this time around.  Also if you are behind a proxy make sure you authenticate on that proxy as well.

Comment: Using apt-get with '-y' and '--allow-unauthenticated' are two unwise habits, avoid them. The interactive prompts are there to protect you, and unsigned packages defeat a *primary* security feature of the package system.